# Case insensitive search on clob fields

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, clob

I'm trying to perform case insensitive search on clob fields.
I don't want to use neither `upper` nor `regexp_like`. `Alter session` is also not an option for me.
I have tried to put an index like this:

```
create index
   ind_ci
on
   table
(
   nlssort( column, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI')
);
```

It seems however  to fail on clob fields. How can I reach the goal using index?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **NLSSORT** function does not support **CLOB** data directly. However, CLOBs can be passed in as arguments through **implicit data conversion**.

You could have a look at [how implicit data conversion happens](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#i55214).

Also, you could read [Oracle – Case Insensitive Sorts & Compares](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/).

Comment: Sorry, there is absolutely  no clue for me.

Comment: The link to documentation clearly elaborates how CLOB can be implicitly handled to convert, so that you can use NLSSORT over CLOB.

Comment: You can convert only until the limit. If the clob filed is longer, then you are not able to convert it in the easy way.

Comment: Because you need to do it in chunks. I just want you to search and learn for your good. Just search how to convert CLOB in chunks.

Comment: If i wanted to search I haven't asked here. Apart from that, the question was how can  I do it with index. Not with conversion.

Comment: NLSSORT doesn't directly support case insensitive sort over CLOB, thus even the case insensitive index is also not supported for CLOB.